# Proof of Convolution Properties

Tags: convolution

Let u,v, w $\in l_1(Z)$.

I need to prove that the following are true:

- their convolution $u*v$ is also in $l_1(Z)$
- if u and v are two probability vectors, then their convolution is also a probability vector

Where do I begin? I have absolutely no idea.

Comment: Is this a homework?